# Filler at the end of a struct for future growth

Tags: c, struct

This [document](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/goodpractice.pdf) called "Good Practices in Library Design, Implementation, and Maintenance" by Ulrich Drepper says (bottom of page 5):

> [...] the type definition should always create at least a minimal
>   amount of padding to allow future growth
>
> [...]
>
> Second, a structure should contain at the end a certain number of fill bytes.
>
> ```
> struct the_struct
> {
>   int foo;
>   // ...and more fields
>   uintptr_t filler[8];
> };
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> If at a later time a field has to be added to the structure the type definition can be changed to this:
>
> ```
> struct the_struct
> {
>   int foo;
>   // ...and more fields
>   union
>   {
>     some_type_t new_field;
>     uintptr_t filler[8];
>   } u;
> };
> ```

I don't see the point of adding this filler at the end of the structure. Yes it means that when adding a new field (`new_field`) to the structure, it doesn't actually grow. But isn't the whole point of adding new fields to a structure that you didn't knew you were going to need them? In this example, what if you want to add not one field but 20? Should you then use a filler of 1k bytes just in case? Also, why does is it important that the size of a struct doesn't change in subsequent versions of a library? If the library provides clean abstractions, that shouldn't matter right? Finally, using a 64 bytes filler (8 uintpr_t (yes, it's not necessarily 64 bytes)) sounds like a waste of memory...

The document doesn't go into the details of this at all. Would you have any explanations to why this advice "adding fillers at the end of struct to plan for future growth" is a good one?

Comment: Maybe binary compatibility? I’d think pointers would be cleaner, though.

Comment: @Ry- I can imagine that, but wouldn't you feel like a library that requires its struct to never change size is oddly designed? (I guess the answer is yes since you mention that pointers looks cleaner)

Comment: You *do* know who Ulrich Drepper is, right?

Comment: @JL2210 yes I do. Doesn't mean I want to blindly do everything he suggests though.

Comment: @Dada I wasn't saying that Ulrich Drepper's advice was good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on circumstances, yes, the size of the structure can be important for binary compatibility.

Consider [`stat()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).  It's typically called like this:

```
struct stat stbuf;
int r = stat(filename, &stbuf);
```

With this setup, if the size of the `stat` structure ever changes, every caller becomes invalid, and will need to be recompiled.  If both the called and the calling code are part of the same project, that may not be a problem.  But if (as in the case of `stat()`, which is a system call into the Unix/Linux kernel) there are lots and lots of callers out there, it's practically impossible to force them all to recompile, so the implication is that the size of the `stat` structure can never be changed.

This sort of problem mainly arises when the caller allocates (or inspects/manipulates) actual instances of the structure.  If, on the other hand, the insides of the structure are only ever allocated and manipulated by library code -- if calling code deals only with pointers to the struct, and doesn't try to interpret the pointed-to structures -- it may not matter if the structure changes.

(Now, with all of that said, there are various other things that can be done to mitigate the issues if a struct has to change size.  There are libraries where the caller allocates instances of a structure, but then passes both a pointer to the structure, and the *size* of the structure as the caller knows it, down into the library code.  Newer library code can then detect a mismatch, and avoid setting or using newer fields which an older caller didn't allocate space for.  And I believe gcc, at least, implements special hooks so that glibc can implement multiple versions of the same structure, and multiple versions of the library functions that use them, so that the correct library function can be used corresponding to the version of the structure that a particular caller is using.  Going back to `stat()`, for example, under Linux there are at least two different versions of the `stat` structure, one which allocates 32 bits for the file size and one which allocates 64.)

Answer (score 1):

> But isn't the whole point of adding new fields to a structure that you
>   didn't knew you were going to need them?

Well yes, if you knew all along that you would need those members, then it would be counter-productive to intentionally omit them.  But sometimes you indeed discover only later that you need some additional fields.  Drepper's recommendations speak to ways to design your code -- specifically your structure definitions -- so that you can add members with the minimum possible side effects.

> In this example, what if you
>   want to add not one field but 20?

You don't start out saying "I'm going to want to add 20 members".  Rather, you start out saying "I may later discover a need for some more members."  That's a prudent position to take.

> Should you then use a filler of 1k
>   bytes just in case?

That's a judgment call.  I recon that a KB of extra space in the structure definition is probably overkill in most cases, but there might be a context where that's reasonable.

> Also, why does is it important that the size of a
>   struct doesn't change in subsequent versions of a library? If the
>   library provides clean abstractions, that shouldn't matter right?

*How important* it is that the size remains constant is a subjective question, but the size is indeed relevant to binary compatibility for shared libraries.  Specifically, the question is whether I can drop a new version of the shared lib in place of the old one, and expect existing programs to work with the new one without recompilation.

Technically, if the definition of the structure changes, even without its size changing, then the new definition is incompatible with the old one as far as the C language is concerned.  In practice, however, with most C implementations, if the structure size is the same and the layout does not change except possibly within previously-unused space, then existing users will not notice the difference in many operations.

If the size *does* change, however, then

- dynamic allocation of instances of the structure will not allocate the correct amount of space.
- arrays of the structure will not be laid out correctly.
- copying from one instance to another via `memcpy()` will not work correctly.
- binary I/O involving instances of the structure will not transfer the correct number of bytes.

There are likely other things that could go wrong with a size change that would (again, in practice) be ok under conversion of some trailing padding into meaningful members.

**Do note**: one thing that might still be a problem if the structure members change without the overall size changing is passing structures to functions by value and (somewhat less so) receiving them as return values.  A library making use of this approach to provide for binary compatibility would do well to avoid providing functions that do those things.

> Finally, using a 64 bytes filler (8 uintpr_t (yes, it's not
>   necessarily 64 bytes)) sounds like a waste of memory...

In a situation in which those 64 bytes per structure is in fact a legitimate concern, then that might trump binary compatibility concerns.  That would be the case if you anticipate a very large number of those structures to be in use at the same time, or if you are extremely memory-constrained.  In many cases, however, the extra space is inconsequential, whereas the extra scope for binary compatibility afforded by including padding is quite valuable.

> The document doesn't go into the details of this at all. Would you
>   have any explanations to why this advice "adding fillers at the end of
>   struct to plan for future growth" is a good one?

Like most things, the recommendation needs to be evaluated relative to your particular context.  In the foregoing, I've touched on most of the points you would want to consider in such an evaluation.